# Why are some folders missing when I switch from "folders view" to "solution view" in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio-2019, folderbrowserdialog

I have cloned a repo in Visual Studio 2019 and whenever I try to open the repo using the "open local folder" option, the folder view loads, here I can see all the projects in the repo but as soon as I switch to the "solution view", a few of my projects and folders go missing. I have tried to right click and add the project again to the solution but as expected, it throws an error saying the project already exists.
What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it?

Comment: Did you try the "Show All Files" button in Solution Explorer?

Comment: @TTT, yes I've already tried that. It doesn't show me the missing files. In fact it seemed like it worked as expand/collapse button for my project